# PHP with XPath doesn't return result with hoster bplaced

Tags: php, xpath

I've created a simple PHP script using XPath to get some content from a specific website.

```
<?php 
   $url = "http://www.weltfussball.de/spielbericht/bundesliga-2017-2018-1899-hoffenheim-borussia-dortmund/";

   $html = new DOMDocument();
   libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
   $html->loadHTMLFile($url);
   $xpath = new DOMXPath($html);
   libxml_clear_errors();

   $xpath_team = $xpath->query('//table[3]/tr/th[1]');
   print_r($xpath_team[0]);
?>
```

The HTML line of interest:

```
<th align="center" width="35%"><a href="/teams/1899-hoffenheim/" title="1899 Hoffenheim">1899 Hoffenheim</a></th>
```

Therefore the expected result should be an array with a value like "1899 Hoffenheim". However, if I update my browser to the [bplaced.net](https://my.bplaced.net) hosted website, I only get errors:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile() [domdocument.loadhtmlfile]: Sorry, an internal error occured. Please report this immediately! (2) in /users/spielerdaten/www/versuch1.php on line 7

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(http://www.weltfussball.de/spielbericht/bundesliga-2017-2018-1899-hoffenheim-borussia-dortmund/) [domdocument.loadhtmlfile]: failed to open stream: operation failed in /users/spielerdaten/www/versuch1.php on line 7
```

[My testwebsite](http://spielerdaten.bplaced.net/versuch1.php)

Now the interesting part is: The same script worked yesterday without any problems. Still, I wasn't able to find any changes, neither by my webhoster, nor on the Website I try to get the content from.

I've tried some changes to my small code sample and checked for errors, but wasn't able to find any. So I tried to google for the first error line that appears (because that one is new to me), but that wasn't really helpful: [Google Search](https://www.google.de/search?ei=WNwrW9GaMI3QwQKA8rSADQ&q=Warning%3A+DOMDocument%3A%3AloadHTMLFile%28%29+%5Bdomdocument.loadhtmlfile%5D%3A+Sorry%2C+an+internal+error+occured&oq=Warning%3A+DOMDocument%3A%3AloadHTMLFile%28%29+%5Bdomdocument.loadhtmlfile%5D%3A+Sorry%2C+an+internal+error+occured&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1303018.1303018.0.1303231.1.1.0.0.0.0.65.65.1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.twRkFZHahnE)

As always, stackoverflow.com is now my last hope to get an idea for what errors I do that cause this mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the table you're hitting with [3] is the table creating this [image]

... but this works, too tired to explain why (maybe tomorrow): `//div[@class="box"]/div[@class="data"]//a`

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I've just used the table name now as target. It's unique, too. The real issue however disappeared on its own. It's weird...